# How to get laravel command arguments outside command, e.g. in service provider?

Tags: php, laravel

I can get arguments in command with this code:

```
$this->argument();
```

But how to get arguments outside ?

If I look at source of argument() function I see :

```
public function argument($key = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $this->input->getArguments();
    }

    return $this->input->getArgument($key);
}
```

I want to detect when command "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed" is running because I want some part of code in models run at localhost enviroment but not in localhost enviroment during seeding...

Comment: what do you mean "outside"? Where do you want to get command line arguments, if not in a command?

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by 'outside'? Can you give us a sample command and the tokens you wished to obtain?

Comment: I said in "service provider". I want to detect when I run "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed"...

Comment: @yivi When I want to detect when "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed" is running and then call this putenv('APP_ENV=seeding');

Comment: where would you be detecting that? where is your code?

Comment: @yivi I already said 2 times, in service provider...It is not matter which service provider because all of them have boot and register methods(all of them have same structure)....

Comment: @yivi you can see my solution down...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mechanism how laravel gets command arguments is pretty complicated. I can detect if app is running in console with \App::runningInConsole() but there is no function which will get arguments, something like :

```
if(\App::runningInConsole()){
    $args = \App::getConsoleArguments(); // doesn't exist :(
}
```

but $_SERVER['argv'] can be usefull here, when "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed" is running in $_SERVER['argv'] is this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => artisan
    [1] => migrate:refresh
    [2] => --seed
)
```

so I can use this code:

```
if( ! empty($_SERVER['argv'][2] )  &&  $_SERVER['argv'][2] == '--seed'){
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I has the same problem building a Laravel SAAS app on AWS, in base to [this project](https://github.com/thinksaydo/envtenant) I modify my ServiceProvider for this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Console\Events\ArtisanStarting;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class MultitenantServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

protected $consoleDispatcher = false;
protected $commands_with_tenant = [
    'migrate', 'migrate:refresh', 'migrate:install', 'migrate:reset', 'migrate:rollback', 
    'migrate:status', 'passport:client', 'passport:install', 'passport:keys'
];

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(){
    if( $this->app->runningInConsole() ){
        $this->registerTenantOption();
        $this->verifyTenantOption();
    }
    // Multitenant re-configure in case of HTTP request
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register(){
    $this->app->singleton('multitenant', function ($app){
        // Register your Multitenant
    });
}

protected function registerTenantOption(){
    $this->app['events']->listen(ArtisanStarting::class, function($event){
        $definition = $event->artisan->getDefinition();
        $definition->addOption(
            new InputOption('--tenant', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The tenant subdomain the command should be run for. Use * or all for every tenant.')
        );
        $event->artisan->setDefinition($definition);
        $event->artisan->setDispatcher($this->getConsoleDispatcher());
    });
}

protected function verifyTenantOption(){
    $this->getConsoleDispatcher()->addListener(ConsoleEvents::COMMAND, function(ConsoleCommandEvent $event){
        if( in_array($event->getCommand()->getName() , $this->commands_with_tenant) ){
            $tenant = $event->getInput()->getParameterOption('--tenant', null);
            if (!is_null($tenant)){
                if ($tenant == 'all'){
                    // Do something with 'all'
                }
                else{
                    // Do something with $tenant
                }
            }
            else{
                $event->getOutput('<error>This command need that specified a tenant client</error>');
                $event->disableCommand();
            }
        }
    });
}

protected function getConsoleDispatcher(){
    if (!$this->consoleDispatcher){
        $this->consoleDispatcher = app(EventDispatcher::class);
    }
    return $this->consoleDispatcher;
}
```

In this class, there is an array with the commands that are needed to verify and use a multitenant config.